# best way to delete and reinsert data to database

Tags: sql, sql-server

so i have a catalog inside a sql server table, i need to be refreshing every 12 hours this catalog, what's the correct way into doing this?

i have been doing a simple delete and afterwards a bulkcopy of the updated data, but im afraid that another process is using this table and might break something.

Cheers,

Comment: All queries related with [Data manipulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Data_manipulation) in SQL is executed one by one with queuing system.

Comment: so it's safe? i mean, i first make a delete slq statment, and after that i do the dumping of new infol what if another process got called in the middle?

Comment: Unless you perform the entire process in an atomic single transaction, there is risk that data consumers may retrieve partially updated data.  Consider loading data into staging structures, and then swapping new data in once the load is compete using sp_rename or `SWITCH`.

Comment: For dumping, database management system will take a snapshot at the exact time of execution. It's safe, definitely. DBMS have the proper algorithms to handle this kind of conflicts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use MERGE feature. It is available in MS SQL Server 2008+, and also add a try/catch - transaction handling. Try following example:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1 
(
     Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    ,Description NVARCHAR(20)
)

CREATE TABLE #Temp2
(
     Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    ,Description NVARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp1 VALUES ('Example1'), ('Example2'), ('');
INSERT INTO #Temp2 VALUES ('Example1'), ('Example4'), ('Example5');

--First values:
SELECT Id, Description FROM dbo.#Temp1;
SELECT Id, Description FROM dbo.#Temp2;

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    --MERGE statement:
    --#Temp1 will be our Target and #Temp2 our Source
    MERGE dbo.#Temp1 AS target
    USING (SELECT Id, Description FROM #Temp2) AS source
    ON (target.Id = source.Id)
    --When rows matched and description from Target will be '', then the delete will happen
    WHEN MATCHED AND target.Description = ''
        THEN DELETE 
    --When rows matched (by their Id, seen previously), then the update will happen:
    WHEN MATCHED 
        THEN UPDATE SET target.Description = source.Description 
    OUTPUT $action;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    RAISERROR('<<Transaction uncommited. Rolling back transaction',10,1);
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
END CATCH

--Final values:
SELECT Id, Description FROM dbo.#Temp1;
SELECT Id, Description FROM dbo.#Temp2;

DROP TABLE #Temp1;
DROP TABLE #Temp2;
```